# Make Subsections Expandable in MediaWiki MobileFrontEnd

Tags: php, mobile, mediawiki

In mobile version of MediaWiki, sections H2 are expandable. I would like the subsections H3 (and H4, if possible) are expandable too. How is it possible? Thank you!

I found this in MobileFrontEnd/includes/MobileFormatter.php, maybe it can be modified:

```
/**
 * Makes sections expandable
 *
 * @param string $s
 * @param string $tagName
 * @return string
 */
protected function headingTransform( $s, $tagName = 'h2' ) {
    wfProfileIn( __METHOD__ );
    $tagRegEx = '<' . $tagName . '.*</' . $tagName . '>';
    $s = $this->pageTransformStart .
        preg_replace(
            '%(' . $tagRegEx . ')%sU', $this->headingTransformStart . '\1' . $this->headingTransformEnd,
            $s
        ) .
        $this->pageTransformEnd;
    wfProfileOut( __METHOD__ );
    return $s;
}

protected function onHtmlReady( $html ) {
    wfProfileIn( __METHOD__ );
    if ( $this->expandableSections ) {
        $tagName = strrpos( $html, '<h1' ) !== false ? 'h1' : 'h2';
        $html = $this->headingTransform( $html, $tagName );
    }
    wfProfileOut( __METHOD__ );
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Suppose someone does not know anything about Mediawiki and its expandable feature. Try to explain what do you mean by these terms and remove as many assumptions as possible while asking questions

Comment: Are you saying your subsections are currently non-expandable i.e. always collapsed? Or are you saying that you want to make them collapsed by default even when one uncollapses their parent section?

Comment: Good question! I'm saying the subsections are always expanded and non-collapsible. I want the subsections to be collapsible, as the main sections (H2) are. See the mobile version of any Wikipedia article to have a look on that.